# Get all instances of a paritcular kind of Nestjs service

Tags: nestjs

It's possible to get all instances of a particular kind of Nest services? Like, for example, all test services?

And then pass them as a constructor parameter of another service?

Comment: How do you differentiate between "regular" and "test" services?

Comment: I still don't know, maybe a wrapper on `Injectable` decorator? Like `TestInjectable`, then it keeps some metadata, making it possible to retrieve from Nest afterwords. Could be feasible?

Comment: I guess the question is _why_ do you want to do this? What's your use case?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel. I'm sorry I should be clear from the beginning, I'm in the process of implementing a [Apify](https://github.com/apify) crawler on a Nest server, this implementation has various bots (wrere it process the pages) and only one crawler (where it make the requests).
The crawler part is a service that implements the bots classes, today it gets them from a decorator class.
Long story short, I want these bots to be Nest services and get them from Nest it self, without modify the crawler service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some time, I was able to implement it, thanks to the article [An extensible NestJS pattern](https://switchit-conseil.com/2020/03/17/an-extensible-nestjs-pattern).

An example can be viewed in [here](https://github.com/Ar-Kan/get-nest-services-instances.git).

Basically it finds the services implementations by searching `ModulesContainer` and its instance from `ModuleRef`.